# Selenium IDE how to make select options visible on click

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a dropdown with a click event set on it. When users clicks some of the options are grayed (disabled) , so user should not be able to select them .

Is is possible through Selenium IDE to emulate this process i.e

- a) invoke click event , which should SHOW the options [VISUAL DISPLAY
  is required]
- b) I run some test (for disabled/enable) options
- c) Select a selectable option

  What is required here is that dropdown options should be visible.

Comment: If you can get Selenium IDE to send the keys alt+down to the select list, it should open the dropdown. I can get it to work in Selenium-Webdriver, but not having any luck in Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the dropdown with the following:

```
Command: getEval
Target: window.document.getElementById('your_dropdown_id').size = window.document.getElementById('your_dropdown_id').length
Value:
```

This will set the size of the dropdown so that all options can be seen.

Comment: thanks for an out-of-box solution (+1) . But in my case it is not suitable . I don't want to break the UI. Imagine if we have lots of options in drop-down , this will whack the GUI :) . But in certain conditions it be will definitely helpful

Comment: If you have large dropdowns, you can always choose to put a cap on the number of options shonw.

Comment: I am accepting this answer partially ,although its not what I desired , but its sth close.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look into installing a browser plug in to help you see the specifics of the JS event handlers on the site you're testing.  One nice one is Visual event:
http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event

This will let you see exactly what element the handler is on, whether it wants a mouse up or mouse down or key press, etc.

Comment: your answer does not seem to be related to Selenium IDE :(